# Convolution between a discrete stochastic signal and a continuous function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, stochastic-processes, convolution, signal-processing

I'm trying to find the convolution between a discrete, stochastic signal (for which I have data at each t) and an exponential decay function (which is continuous in t). Now I know that one can convolve two discrete signals, or two continuous signals, or a continuous signal and a delta impulse train. But can someone please advice on how I can convolve a continuous function with a discrete signal?

Fairly stuck on this; so any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Think of the discrete signal as a sum of deltas, $x(t) = \sum x[k] \delta(t-k) $. Note that    1. $h(t) * \delta(t-k) = h(t-k)$, and 2. Convolution is linear. This leads to $ h*x (t) = \sum x[k] h(t-k) $.

Comment: Another option if you sample your exponent with the same resolution.